# Tools/metrics for evaluating gazebo in action?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
Are there methods to generate metrics of how "well" gazebo is running/performing?
gzstats publishes factor values, and you can also go the gztopic hz path, but is that all that exists?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/52/tools/metrics-for-evaluating-gazebo-in-action?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-01-11**:
What do you have in mind?  How would you characterize (and measure) "good" performance?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-01-14**:
Not sure what to measure, but in the past the Gazebo 0.8 when the simulation ran as fast as possible the frame rate (for the GUI??) gave a rough metric of the computer's ability to model the world.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-01-14**:
If I recall correctly, this frames per second quantity varied with system load, the number of objects, and the complexity of objects in an understandable way. If one needed to benchmark simulation computers, simulation environments, tasks, I'm not sure what an appropriate metric would be currently.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-01-23**:
How is performance measure currently? Is it something like `ps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are a couple ways to measure performance. Keep in mind that any value you get is dependent on both your computer and the world you're simulating.

1. `gztopic hz <topic_name>`: will return the average time (over a sliding window) at which a messages are received. Keep in mind that this is not time time at which the message was generated.
2. `gztopic view <topic_name>`: This is only applicable to Gazebo 1.4+ and only for topics which produce laser or image data. The widget that appears will show the average time at which the data was generated.
3. `gzstats`: This will show, among other things, the real-time factor. A real-time factor of 1.0 means that Gazebo is running at real-time. A factor <1.0 means that Gazebo is running slower than real-time.
4. Use valgrind. This will give you very detailed look at what Gazebo is doing.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0